# Implement the Unix 'dc' utility in C

Tags: c, dc

I am just hoping on getting some tips on how to get started on my assignment.
It reads as follows:

"Implement a program that behaves similarly to the 'dc' utility, which evaluates expressions in a postfix notation, and also supports additional computations using variables and macro strings. Feel free to experiment with the existing utility and consulting its manual pages.
The assignment will support only a subset of the complete utility: 
-- all numeric values will be integers, only using radix 10

-- numbers may be assumed to be within the range of 32-bit signed numbers

-- all register names will be alphanumeric (a subset of those dc allows)

-- no command line options or arguments will be required

-- only the following commands are are required (listed in the same order as the manual) 
   p n f + - * / % ^ c d r s l S L x > !> < !< = != q #

Some key differences between the assignment and the existing utility: 
-- all input will be through standard input only (but not necessarily keyboard)

-- register stacks are initially not empty, but filled with infinite zeros

-- the q command will exit the program, regardless of macro call nesting level

-- additional spaces may appear between input tokens for legibility 
   (the space is not a command or a value or a register name)"

I honestly don't know where to start... Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is an assignment and you do not know where to start here are some hints:

- Start with reading the stdin and split it into tokens
- implement the stack to store operands and results
- implement a few operations like +,-,*,/
- make it all working
- then implement the missing features one by one

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!
Im still trying to understand the syntax of dc, which tokens should i look for first?

Comment: decimal numbers and four arithmetic operations. Make it working - while you implement this you will get the idea how to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

@Serge has given a good outline of how to start, but you seem a bit at sea about just what `dc` does, so here are a few pointers for that.

- The assignment says that you should experiment with the real `dc` program.  Do this, if you haven't already done so, and you should learn quite a bit.  (If you haven't done this, why not?)
- Check out the Basic Operations section of the [Wikipedia page on `dc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_%28computer_program%2).
- Read the `dc` man page.  You'll find it confusing the first time, but read it again and try out what you see there with the actual program.
- If you're confused by the whole idea of *postfix notation* see the Wikipedia page on [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), which is another name for the same thing.

This should let you understand the following very simple examples, as well as predict what they do:

- `3 p`
- `3 4 * p`
- `3 4 5 + * p`
- `3 4 + 5 * p`

Your assignment goes quite a way beyond, but if you get this much implemented you'll be more than half-way there.